# How to populate a list of Strings with a separate List

Tags: scala

I'm tring to populate a list of Strings containing a header and a footer String with the main contents being a locally read file.
The text file 'textFile' below contains a list of Strings.

Here's what I'm trying :

```
     var fileList = List[String]()
     val bigFile = io.Source.fromFile("d:\\textFile.txt")
     val groupedLines = bigFile.getLines.grouped(20000).zipWithIndex
    groupedLines.foreach(group => {
        val (lines, index) = group
        fileList.addString(new StringBuilder("begin"))

        //How can I add the contents of the file here to the val fileList ???
        fileList.add(lines.)
        fileList.addString(new StringBuilder("end"))
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following approach is much more natural in Scala:

```
val bigFile = io.Source.fromFile("textFile.txt")
val groupedLines = bigFile.getLines.grouped(20000)
val fileList = groupedLines.flatMap("begin" +: _ :+ "end").toList
```

No `var`s, mutable collections, or folding necessary. You could write the last line equivalently as:

```
val fileList = groupedLines.map("begin" +: _ :+ "end").flatten.toList
```

This isn't as idiomatic as the `flatMap` version, but it makes what we're doing a little clearer: we're bookending each of the groups and then smashing them all together.

Comment: what task is the _ accomplishing in last line, reason im asking is that last line does not seem to compile ?

Comment: It's called placeholder syntax—it's just shorthand for `groupedLines.flatMap(x => "begin" +: x :+ "end").toList`. It should work (and does for me). What's the error message.

Answer (score 4):

Since List is immutable, I think you would either want to:

Use a ListBuffer which is mutable and will allow you to append data:

```
val fileList = new ListBuffer[String]()
fileList += "begin"
```

Or, you could try using foldLeft on groupedLines to produce a new structure:

```
groupedLines.foldLeft(List[String]()){ (newList, items) => 
    newList ::: "begin" :: items._1 ::: "end" :: Nil
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a fold or recursion is probably better style, but to answer your question directly, you change the reference of fileList to a new List each time. Not sure why you're messing with `StringBuilder`s if you just want a list of Strings.

`List` isn't a good choice of collection for appending things, although you can use it if you prepend, then reverse everything at the end. I'd use `Vector`, but here it is with `List`:

```
fileList ::= "begin"
lines foreach {fileList ::= _}
fileList ::= "end"
```

then after the `groupedLines foreach` block

```
fileList = fileList.reverse
```

note, `a ::= b` is syntactic sugar for `a = b :: a`.